# Change automatically a label in c# forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form in C# Windows Forms, every time a button is clicked I change my index, and I want to change the content of a Label based on this index. The only choice I found is label_click however I want the change to be automatically. Any idea about this?

```
    // lines a gloab list of strings and index changes from a button click
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "videos/" + lines[index] + ".mp4"; 
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (index >= 1)
            index--;
    }
```

Comment: `string` means `TextBox` ?

Comment: Basically my string is the followign "videos/" + lines[index] + ".mp4";  which changes via lines[index] a global List<String>

Comment: you are searching a way to change label let's say in every 3 second ?

Comment: every time that a button is clicked. I updated my question! Index is changed from two buttons.

Comment: if you want to change label text on button click do it simply.  `private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
   label1.Text = "videos/" + lines[index] + ".mp4"; 
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(){/*initialization here*/}
int index = 0;

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Ensure index is inside List bounds.
    index = Math.Min(lines.length -1 , index + 1);
    ChangeLabelText()
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Ensure index is inside List bounds.
   index = Math.Max(0 , index - 1);
   ChangeLabelText()
} 

void ChangeLabelText() => label1.Text = "videos/" + lines[index] + ".mp4";
```